# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Specified key was too long and connection refused simultaneously happening

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

In my java+gradle spring backend, while testing with localhost and attempting to connect to a mysql DB on localhost, I'm getting an error that specified key was too long, which I suspect has something to do with encoding overfilling the DB in it's regular setting (to my knowledge, some encodings take up more bytes which overflow the default setting). But, it's also claiming that the connection is refused which implies that the port isn't listening. I thought this was odd because a telnet localhost 1433 returns that the connection succeeded. I'm not particularly sure how to debug the issue nor how these 2 relate, can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Edit: Here's my application.properties

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store-password=${Password}
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:baeldung.jks
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12


spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:1433/${databasename}?useSSL=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=${username}
spring.datasource.password={$dbpassword}
```

Comment: Please, shaere your code

Comment: Just added my application.properties, my apologies. I could add my Java code but I don't think it's relevant to the error I'm seeing, as the issue seems to be something with the connection to the db itself.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it had something to do with the engine that was being used to create the db (inconsistency with that of the running SQL server, which was using innoDB). This line:

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect

in application.properties fixed it and got it to use the right engine. It can connect fine now.